# Python 3.5: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, csv, errno

I learned Python but hadn't used it in a few months so I am perhaps rusty. I am just trying to start a project by reading from a csv text file. I understand that there are several questions on this site about this error, but I haven't found one that fixes the issue. This is probably really basic and I wanted to figure this out without posting a question, but after several hours I really don't get it. Sorry if I missed a question that has answered this, but I have checked a lot of questions first. Here is all of my code:

```
import csv
with open('C:\\Users\\Ben.Brittany-PC\\Documents\\stats.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

and the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Ben.Brittany-PC\\Documents\\stats.txt'
```

Comment: It means just that, there is no such file on your disk. Tripple-check your file path.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it's the backslashes. Have you tried adding an r in front on your path to make r'C:\Users\Ben.Brittany-PC\Documents\stats.txt', 'rb' ? This will make the string be read raw and backslashes will not need to be escaped.

Comment: Nope, its not. The filename has no unescape backslash issues.

Comment: Aah. Read the error output and jumped the gun without seeing that he had them escaped. Can you paste that string into windows explorer and have the document be opened? Then at least you know that the path is right and can then focus on case.

Answer (score 0):

The file C:\Users\Ben.Brittany-PC\Documents\stats.txt does not exist. Check the path (case sensitive).